# How to create a Tour on the homepage?

Tags: 8

I created a Tour with the Tour UI module and I was unable to activate the tour on the homepage.

The homepage of my site is the default view of drupal 8 with the machine name frontpage

How to activate the tour on the homepage ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every time a page is rendered, the Tour module load all guided tours for this one. Those tours are added at the end of the DOM (with hook_page_bottom) with a css 'hidden' class. Then the Tour JS script (tour.js) handles those hidden elements by watching a triggering html element targeted by the id **toolbar-tab-tour**. If any tour is registered for the current page, that **toolbar-tab-tour**element will also be hidden by tour.js. 
I did this thing for showing a student role tour. I simply created a plugin block within my module:

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block;

```
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'StudentTourBlock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "student_tour_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("Student tour block"),
 * )
 */
class StudentTourBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    if (\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('access tour') && !\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('access toolbar')) {

      $build = [
        'tour_button' => [
          '#type' => 'html_tag',
          '#tag' => 'button',
          '#value' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> ' . $this->t('Help'),
          '#attributes' => [
            'id' => 'toolbar-tab-tour',
            'class' => ['btn btn-success btn-xs hidden-sm hidden-xs']
          ],
          '#cache' => [
            'contexts' => [
              'user.permissions'
            ]
          ],
          '#attached' => [
            'library' => [
              'tour/tour',
            ],
          ],
        ]
      ];
      return $build;
    }
    else
      return [];
  }

}
```

Don't forget to attach the **tour/tour** library :)

Comment: Thank you. I use Tour WHO, is there not a way to do this since the Drupal administration ?